# Changing HTML of an element dynamically through a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to change the HTML of an element based on a variable that is passed as an attribute of a directive.

The content is supposed to be changing back to the 'This is the original content...'. How come it doesn't work?

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div data-loading-data='{{testObj}}'>
    <p> This is the original content. changingVar is '{{testObj.changingVar}}'</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.testObj = {};
  $scope.testObj.changingVar = false;

  $timeout(function() {
    console.log("time out is done ! the original content should be restored now (from somewhere inside the directive!)");
    $scope.testObj.changingVar = true;
  }, 5000);

});

app.directive('loadingData', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: 'false',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      var originalHTML = elem[0].innerHTML;
      elem.replaceWith("<p>This is modified content</p>");

      // When testObj.changingVar will be true, I want the original content (which is stored in var 'originalHTML') to be set!
      // How to do?
      // ........................................... ?
      // ........................................... ?
    }
  }
});
```

First answer was useful; sorry, I accidently saved the jsfiddle with some commented out parts. Updated now!

There was an answer which suggested using objects is useful `(passed by reference)` instead of passing a single variable `(passed by value)` - that was great to know.

---

**I updated the jsFiddle again to illustrate what I am trying to do better:**

https://jsfiddle.net/4xbLrg5e/6/

Comment: check the updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things you are passing `testObj` means you don't want to use inherited scope with directive.

So,I am assuming you want to use [isolated scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

As per this,
Here is the changes,

HTML :

```
<div test-data='testObj'>
    <p> This is the original content. changingVar is '{{testObj.changingVar}}'</p>
  </div>
```

Directive JS : 
There are some correction,

```
1. replace : false; // implicitly it is false and not 'false';

2. You should not  replace directive with html until unless you dont want to refer it again.
```

You can put [watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)  to properties of passed object if you want update the html as per data changes.

You should use [isolated scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) with directive as per above assumption.
This is nothing but `passed by reference` using `=`

```
app.directive('loadingData', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: false,
    scope : {testData:'=testData'},
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        var originalHTML = elem[0].innerHTML;
        elem.html("<p>This is modified content</p>");

        scope.$watch(function(){
                return scope.testData.changingVar;
        },function(nVal){
            console.log('1')
            elem.html("<p>Here is the original content</p>");
        })
     }
  }
});
```

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uq7sfep3/)